# Working on a Fibonnaci/mysequence code

Tags: c, fibonacci

I was working on a code that is suppose to calculate the sequence:

```
           a(n+2)=-2(n+1)+3a(n)       a(0)=2     a(1)= -1
```

Unfortunately I cannot figure it out. I'm recently new at this (about a month) and I'm going to try best to do this on my own, but I will need some help. Thank you for whoever decides to help me.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int mysequence(int n)
{ 
  if (n==0) return 2;
  if (n==1) return -1;
  if (n==2) return 8;
  return (2 * mysequence(n+1) + mysequence(n+2))/3;
}

int main()
{
  int n;
  printf("Enter n = ");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  printf("%d\n",mysequence(n));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Based on the code, I assume that's supposed to be `-2a(n+1)`, not `-2(n+1)`. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the line `return (2 * mysequence(n+1) + mysequence(n+2))/3` carefully and compare it with what you know about the sequence:
`a(n+2)=-2(n+1)+3a(n)`.

They have nothing in common.

What you want is `return (-2*mysequence(n-1) + 3*mysequence(n-2))`.
As to why, well the coefficients should be clear enough, they are just copied from the definition. The reason we call the next level of recursion with `n-1` and `n-2` is also quite simple, observe: 
`a(n+2)=-2(n+1)+3a(n)` -> substitute `n` for `n-2` -> `a(n)=-2(n-1)+3a(n-2)`.

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked great and I fully understand your explanation. The line that I wrote I derived by solving for a(n), but I did not realize that there was a much efficient way of handling it. Thank you once again!

Comment: @Edward It may have produced a program that generates output, but unfortunately it's wrong according to the recurrence you gave in the question.

Comment: @Gene huh, just noticed that strictly speaking, you are right. However, if you take a look at the case for `n==2`, you will  see that the recurrence has to be in the form of `a(n+2) = -2a(n+1) + 3a(n)`, and an a just went AWOL. (It wouldn't add up otherwise.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you came up with this line:

```
return (2 * mysequence(n+1) + mysequence(n+2))/3;
```

But that's not correct. For one thing, `mysequence(n)` would call `mysequence(n+1)` (and `mysequence(n+2)`), which would call `mysequence(n+2)`, which would call `mysequence(n+3)`, which would call `mysequence(n+4)`, etc. - it should be easy to see that you'll never reach `mysequence(0)` or `mysequence(1)` (assuming `n > 1`), thus it would keep going forever, or at least until you run out of memory, since you're increasing instead of decreasing the parameter in subsequent calls.

Let's start from the beginning by first converting this:

```
a(n+2) = -2a(n+1) + 3a(n)
```

Into something that looks more like the code: (by subtracting 2 from each `n+c`)
(on the left side we'd like `a(n)`, since the function takes the parameter `n`, not `n+2`)

```
a(n) = -2a(n-1) + 3a(n-2)
```

Now we simply need to put that in the code. Replace:

```
return (2 * mysequence(n+1) + mysequence(n+2))/3;
```

With

```
return -2 * mysequence(n-1) + 3 * mysequence(n-2);
```

Also, you don't really need to specifically cater for `n == 2` - it will be handled correctly by the above statement.

Comment: I came up with that line by solving for a(n), but now I realized my mistake on that. Thank you for your insight!

Answer (score 1):

The **n** will be more bigger until unlimited number when run your program.

I think you need change the function to :

```
a(n)=-2(n-1)+3a(n-2) a(0)=2 a(1)= -1
```

Replace **n+2** with **n**. It will make **n** smaller until 1 and 0.

Then code will be:

```
int mysequence(int n)
{
    if (n == 0) return 2;
    if (n == 1) return -1;
    return (-2 * mysequence(n - 1) + mysequence(n - 2)) / 3;
}
```

**note: n >= 0**

Answer (score 0):

Your recursive function is infinitely so!  The value of n passed in is incremented in the recursive calls, but the base cases for the recursion assume they decrease.

You'll need what is called a change of variables.  Let m = n + 2.  So n = m - 2.  Then the recurrence you've given becomes

```
a(m) = -2 * (m - 1) + 3 * a(m - 2)
```

Implement this as a recursive function.  Since the value passed as the argument on the right hand side is now *less* than that the left, the small base case values will be reached for any m >= 0.

Comment: I used both this answer and and yours (Xarn) to understand, however it was yours Xarn that I could more easily understand.